# mean variance of uniform distribution over [0,1] MATLAB

Tags: matlab, mean, variance

What is the best way in Matlab to get the mean and variance of a uniform distribution over `[0,1]`?.

Comment: You do realise that MATLAB includes help documentation? Try there first for the definitive answer

Comment: Your question is vague. Do you want to know how to calculate the *expected* [mean](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expected_value#Definition) and [variance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variance#Definition) of a uniform distribution or do you want to simply compute the mean and variance of a set of samples that just happen to be from a uniform distribution?

Comment: The mean and variance of a Uniform (0,1) or even a Uniform(a,b) random variable are known formulas.  See my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mean and variance of an empirical distribution are calculated the same way for any distribution:

```
%# create uniform distribution
N = 1000;
dist = rand(N); %# N values, uniformly distributed between 0 and 1

%# calculate mean and variance
distributionMean = mean(dist);
distributionVariance = var(dist);
```

This approach provides an estimate for the mean and variance of the distribution from which your sample was drawn. Note that with larger N, `distributionMean` will approach 0.5, and `distributionVariance` will approach 1/12. If that's the values you're really interested in, the useful Matlab command is

```
web('http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_distribution_(continuous)')
```

Comment: Depending if you want to calculate the sample variance (as opposed to estimating the underlying population variance), you might want to use `var(dist,1)`. See the doc for `var` http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/var.html

Comment: 1000 values is going to give you a pretty mediocre estimate of mean and variance.

Comment: @Jason S: Well, if you want to know the exact mean and variance, you better look it up on Wikipedia. Whether an error of ~5% is pretty or mediocre is in the eye of the beholder.

Comment: I guess my point is that this is an *estimate* (not a *calculation*) of mean and variance. Your answer does not state this, nor does it state how the number of values (1000) affects the accuracy of mean and variance. It's easy enough to use 10,000 or 100,000 values (the latter improving accuracy of the mean by a factor of 10). I was close to upvoting your answer, but not the way it is presently worded.

Comment: (clarification: it is a *calculation* of sample set mean and variance. It is an *estimate* of the distribution mean and variance.)

Comment: @Jason S: Fair enough. Better?

Answer (score 2):

The mean and variance of a Uniform (0,1) or even a Uniform(a,b) random variable are known formulas.

For `X~Uniform(a,b)`,

```
mean(X) = (a+b)/2

var(X) = (1/12)*((b-a)^2)
```

Set `a = 0` and `b = 1` for the desired result.

Read more [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_distribution_(continuous)).